# App exits without calling any callbacks on back press on device, flutter

Tags: flutter

App Entry Point:

```
void main() {
  runWhat();}

void runWhat() async{

//getLoggedInSharedPrefs() gets logged in state from SharedPrefs
  await getLoggedInSharedPrefs().then((isLoggedIn) {
    if(isLoggedIn) {
      runApp(Home()); // User is Logged in go to Home; 
    } else {
      runApp(new MyApp()); // Login Screen - separate from Home
    }
  });
}
```

In `Home`, I want to alert User on pressing back and alert if they want to exit out of app. But neither `_onWillPop` nor `dispose` get called

Home is a separate screen from MyApp and is not the body of MyApp

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    HomeState homeState() => new HomeState();
    return homeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
         child: new MaterialApp(.....

    @override
      void dispose() {
        print('dispose: $this');
        super.dispose();
      }

     Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
        print("Poppoing Home on will popo");
        return showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
                    title: new Text('Home - Are you sure?'),
                    content: new Text('Do you want to exit'),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      new FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        child: new Text('No'),
                      ),
                      new FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => exit(0),
                        child: new Text('Yes'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
            ) ??
            false;
      }


... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange how you've set up your app as in your `WillPopScope` should be within `MaterialApp` and `Scaffold`:

**App Class**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: HomePage(),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

**Your Page**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: _onWillPop,
               child:new Center(
              child: new Text("Home Page"),
            ),
          );
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
                content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                    child: new Text('No'),
                  ),
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                    child: new Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ) ??
        false;
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: MyApp() and Home() are two separate screens not as you described. Home() is not the body of MyApp(). I am changing the question to make it clear.

Comment: Well then just do as my example but put it in Home instead?

Answer (score 0):

Taking hint from @SnakeyHips I modified my code as below but I needed Scaffold to be stateful for tab navigation

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Georgia'),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  ....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    .... 
  }

 }
```

Comment: Glad it worked! I'd also appreciate it if you could accept my answer :)

Comment: Does it matter what context we pass to Navigator while pushing? For ex: does passing context from a Builder down in a widget tree same as context from Stateful widget Build function? Just curious!

Comment: Usually the context from the builder should be from the stateful widget so then the Navigator knows to pop back to the stateful widget context. Again though, if you could accept my answer as the answer that'll be great :)